# How to display and merge table from PostgreSQL using php?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to display data from data base. I want to make it grouped. Here is the template
[image]

I made the code like this :

```
<?php
    $queg=pg_query("SELECT agentgroup.leadername,agentgroup.reviewername, agentgroup.supervisorname, agent.onlinename from agentgroup left join agent on agentgroup.agentid=agent.agentid order by agentgroup.leadername");

    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Number </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Agent Group </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Coach </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Supervisor </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Agent Online Name </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" ></td>";
   $gcount=1;
    while($grow=pg_fetch_array($queg)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\" rowspan=\"8\" align=\"center\"> ".$gcount++."</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\" rowspan=\"8\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['leadername']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\" rowspan=\"8\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['reviewername']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\" rowspan=\"8\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['supervisorname']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['onlinename']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\" rowspan=\"4"align=\"center\"><a href=\"#\" >edit</a></td>
                    </tr>";}
?>
```

But I got chaos.this is the current output 
[image]

Any help to display those data? Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database design was wrong I guess. In case its already happen, than u shouldnt display the data like that. try to pass the specified data to new page via url ( href ) and then display them one by one by specify the coach or agent group

```
<?php
    $queg=pg_query("SELECT distinct  leadername, reviewername, supervisorname from agentgroup order by leadername");

    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Number </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Agent Group </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Coach </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Supervisor </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" ></td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" ></td>";

    $gcount=1;
    while($grow=pg_fetch_array($queg))
    {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\"  align=\"center\"> ".$gcount++."</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\"  align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['leadername']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\"  align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['reviewername']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"forma\"  align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$grow['supervisorname']." </td>";
            echo "<td class=\"form2\" align=\"center\"><a href=viewpergorup.php?viewnamegroup=".urlencode($grow['leadername'])."><img src=\"image\\view.png\" width=\"20px\" height=\"20px\" style=\"padding-left:22%;cursor:pointer;\"></td>";

        }
```

make the page : view_agentgroup. There the details is displayed

Comment: Since u get the value of 'leadername', u can use it in other page to display all the data related. Cheers :)